# How to separate the data in python series based on week to plot them in cycle graph?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

i have five week seasonal data in a single series with date and time, how do i separate it based on week wise,like week1,week2...week5 so that i can plot all the week data in same graph.

i tried re sampling the data on day wise by finding the mean. but the data is still in single series. i just want to separate the data based on weeks like 2019-04-02 to 2019-04-08 in different dataframe,2019-04-08 to 2019-04-16 in separate df

```
df.open.resample('M').mean()
date    pageload  day
0     2019-04-02 10:48:00  -79.002023  Tue
1     2019-04-02 10:49:00   33.563679  Tue
2     2019-04-02 10:50:00  -76.448319  Tue
3     2019-04-02 10:51:00   30.974816  Tue
4     2019-04-02 10:52:00  -68.789962  Tue
5     2019-04-02 10:53:00   30.593374  Tue
21    2019-04-16 11:34:00   40.333445  Fri
```

data frame separated on week wise. To plot all the week data in single graph.

Comment: Refer [How to create minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: is your data frame indexed on date time ?, can you add first few lines of your data frame in your question?

Comment: yes it is indexed on date time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not **think** you want to resample like Shijith is showing. I think you want different dataframes for each week. IMO you want to use [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html) ([doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)) for that.  The Pandas [Groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html) function can be used to split the data in a dataframe by columns or indexes. The method returns a pandas groupby object which can be used to perform operations on the groups before merging them back.

In the snippet of code, I first create a column to group the data by (i.e. the "weeks" column). Than I group the data by the weeks column. This creates a groupby object which among others, consists of a dictionary that has the unique values of the "weeks" column as keys and list of indices of the dataframe which have the same value for the "weeks" column as values. This can be seen by typing `print(grps.groups)` in the console. Than I loop over the keys of the groups and add each of the week dataframe into a dictionary by calling the `get_group` method on the groupby object.

```py
import pandas as pd

# Make sample data
index=pd.date_range(start='2014-01-01', end='2014-1-31',freq='D')
df = pd.DataFrame({"vals":np.random.randint(-5,5,len(index))}, index=index)
df["csum"] = df.vals.cumsum()
# Add a column for weeks to enable grouping
df["weeks"] = df.index.week

# Group the data
grps = df.groupby("weeks")

# split the group into separate dataframes
df_dict = {}
for gi in grps.groups:
    df_dict[gi] = grps.get_group(gi)
```

I start off with something like this:

```
            vals  csum  weeks
2014-01-01     4     4      1
2014-01-02    -5    -1      1
...
2014-01-30    -2    -9      5
2014-01-31    -5   -14      5
```

and end up with dataframe like the following

```
1
            vals  csum  weeks
2014-01-01     4     4      1
2014-01-02    -5    -1      1
2014-01-03    -4    -5      1
2014-01-04     4    -1      1
2014-01-05    -5    -6      1
2
            vals  csum  weeks
2014-01-06    -5   -11      2
2014-01-07     2    -9      2
2014-01-08     4    -5      2
2014-01-09    -1    -6      2
2014-01-10    -1    -7      2
2014-01-11    -3   -10      2
2014-01-12    -2   -12      2
```

Comment: This is working can you explain this further? and what is csum?

Comment: I will put more explanation in the answer. "csum" is just a random data column which makes the cumulative sum of "vals". It does not have any relevance to this. Also, I have linked the function in my answer if you want more detailed explanation for it.

Answer (score 0):

If your data frame `df` is indexed on date

```
   print(df)
                 High         Low        Open       Close    Volume   Adj Close
Date                                                                            
2019-04-01  191.679993  188.380005  191.639999  191.240005  27862000  191.240005
2019-04-02  194.460007  191.050003  191.089996  194.020004  22765700  194.020004
2019-04-03  196.500000  193.149994  193.250000  195.350006  23271800  195.350006
2019-04-04  196.369995  193.139999  194.789993  195.690002  19114300  195.690002
2019-04-05  197.100006  195.929993  196.449997  197.000000  18526600  197.000000
2019-04-08  200.229996  196.339996  196.419998  200.100006  25881700  200.100006
2019-04-09  202.850006  199.229996  200.320007  199.500000  35768200  199.500000
2019-04-10  200.740005  198.179993  198.679993  200.619995  21695300  200.619995
2019-04-11  201.000000  198.440002  200.850006  198.949997  20900800  198.949997
2019-04-12  200.139999  196.210007  199.199997  198.869995  27760700  198.869995
```

do,

```
weekly_summary = pd.DataFrame()
weekly_summary['Open'] = df.open.resample('W').first()
print(weekly_summary)  

                  Open
Date                  
2019-04-07  191.639999
2019-04-14  196.419998
```

if its not indexed on date time do,

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
df.sort_index(inplace=True)

weekly_summary = pd.DataFrame()
weekly_summary['Open'] = df.open.resample('W').first()
```

for the above code data frame will be indexed on 'sundays' , if you want it to be indexed on 'Mondays' (i.e., starting day of the week), do as below.

```
weekly_summary = pd.DataFrame()
weekly_summary['Open'] = df.open.resample('W',loffset=pd.offsets.timedelta(days=-6)).first()
print(weekly_summary)  

                  Open
Date                  
2019-04-01  191.639999
2019-04-08  196.419998
```